# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIImage systemImageNamed:]:

Tags: ios, swift

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIImage systemImageNamed:]:**

The above error is received on running the below code:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
```

Comment: This works only in iOS 13 and later

Comment: What iOS do you use?

Comment: I don't think the compiler would let him compile if he wasn't targeting - that's definitely a valid system symbol just looked it up.. and Xcode wouldn't let him run it on a device that wasn't being targeted. Did you import UIKit in the file? If you're using SwiftUI I know the syntax is `Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")` instead too but I haven't used it so unsure if UIImage fails like this.

Comment: I didn't know that it works only in iOS 13 or later. My bad!